# AutoHotKey WinActive returns wrong value when changing window focus

Tags: autohotkey

In my AutoHotKey script I'm using `#IfWinActive` to detect if the Roblox window is in focus, and then press the number `1` button whenever left clicking the mouse, like this:

```
#IfWinActive, Roblox
    LButton::
        MouseClick, Left
        SendInput, {1}
    return
#IfWinActive
```

It works great, except for when I'm clicking out of the Roblox window back to another window. It still fires this code on the first click, resulting in it typing the number `1` into Notepad (or whatever window I switch focus to).

I figured that when I'm clicking on Notepad the focus is still on the Roblox window, which is why the code still fires. So I tried changing the code to this:

```
#IfWinActive, Roblox
    LButton::
        Sleep, 100
        if WinActive("Roblox")
        {
            MouseClick, Left
            SendInput, {1}
        }
    return
#IfWinActive
```

Assuming that by the time the `Sleep` finished the focus would have shifted to the Notepad window and `If WinActive("Roblox")` would return false, but it still returns true and types `1` into Notepad.

I also tried using `StartTimer` and a label, thinking that maybe the `Sleep` wasn't asynchronous, but that has the same problem as well.

Anybody know how to get around this issue? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways we can achieve this. TL;DR for solution, check the yellow part of this post.
Firstly I'll address the *problems* in your code:

1. Usage of [`MouseClick`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/MouseClick.htm) over [`Click`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Click.htm). Technically nothing wrong, but `Click` is said to be more reliable in some situations and easier to use. Looks cleaner as well.
2. Wrapping `1` in `{}` is not needed and does nothing for you here. In some cases you may even produce unwanted behavior by doing this. In a send command, `{}` is used to escape keys that have special meaning, or to define keys that you can't just type in. More about this from the [documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Send.htm).
3. Having a somewhat of a *bad* [WinTitle](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/WinTitle.htm) that you're matching against. Again, nothing technically wrong, but right now you match any window that starts with the word Roblox. Shouldn't be too hard accidentally match the wrong window.
   A quick and a very effective solution would be matching against the process name of your Roblox window.
   So `#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Roblox.exe` or in an if-statement `if (WinActive("ahk_exe Roblox.exe"))` (assuming that's the process' name, I have no idea)
   For an absolutely fool proof way could match against the hwnd of the Roblox window. However, that's maybe a bit overkill and you couldn't *really* use it with `#IfWinActive` either. An example I'll write below will use this that though.

However, *problems* 1 and 2 can be entirely avoided by doing this neat way of remapping a key (remapping is pretty much what you're doing here).
`~LButton::1`
Ok, so why does that work?
`key::key` is just the syntax to easily do a basic remap, and with [`~`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Symbols) we specify that the hotkey isn't consumed when it fires.

---

Cool, but now onto the actual problem you're having.
So what went wrong with the sleeping thing? Well since you're consuming the hotkey, all you're actually doing is firing the hotkey, waiting 100ms, then checking if Roblox is active. Well yes, it will still be active since nothing was ever done to switch focus away from it.
If you were to not consume the left clicking action, it would work, **but** it's definitely not a good idea. You do not want to sleep inside a hotkey statement. AHK does not have true multithreading and unless you would've specified a higher [`#MaxThreadsPerHotkey`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_MaxThreadsPerHotkey.htm) for your hotkey, all subsequent presses of the hotkey would be totally ignored for that 100ms.
So yes, with specifying a higher amount of threads that can run for that hotkey, it would kind of make this solution work, but it's still bad practice. We can come up with something better.

With timers you can avoid sleeping in the hotkey statement. Sounds like you tried the timers already, but I can't be sure it went right since code wasn't provided so I'll go over it:

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Roblox.exe
~LButton::SetTimer, OurTimersCallbackLabel, -100 ;-100 specifies that it runs ONCE after 100ms has passed
#IfWinActive

OurTimersCallbackLabel:
    if (WinActive("ahk_exe Roblox.exe"))
        SendInput, 1
return
```

---

> And now onto the real solution, to which @user3419297 seems to have beat me to, just as I'm writing this line of text.

Using the up event of your LButton press as the hotkey.

```
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe Roblox.exe
~LButton Up::SendInput, 1
#IfWinActive
```

This way the down event has already switched focus of the window and our hotkey wont even fire.
Note that here we unfortunately can't use the `key::key` way of remapping I described above.

---

## Bonus:

Here's something that could be used if the up event of our keypress wouldn't be desirable, or somehow the window switching of the active window was delayed.

```
RobloxHwnd := WinExist("ahk_exe Roblox.exe")

#If, RobloxUnderMouse()
~LButton::1
#If

RobloxUnderMouse()
{
    global RobloxHwnd ;specify that we're using the variable defined outside of this function scope
    ;could've also ran the code to get Roblox's hwnd here every time, but that would be wasteful

    MouseGetPos, , , HwndUnderMouse ;we don't need the first two parameters
    return RobloxHwnd == HwndUnderMouse ;are they the same hwnd? (return true or false)
}
```

Here we're first storing the hwnd of our Roblox to the variable `RobloxHwnd`.
Note that Roblox would need to be running before we run this script, and if you restart robox, script would need to be restarted as well.
So adding some way of updating the value of this variable on the fly would be good, maybe under some hotkey.

Then by using [`#If`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_If.htm) we're evaluating an expression (in our case, running a function and evaluating its return value) every time we're about to attempt to fire the hotkey. If the expression evaluates to true, we fire the hotkey.
Usage of `#If` is actually **not** recommended, and it is good practice to avoid using if at all possible. However, you wont encounter any problems in a script this small, so using `#If` is going to be very convenient here.
If you were to have a bigger script in which there's a lot of code running often, you'd be likely to run into problems.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem in this case is that the hotkey is fired immediately after LButton is pressed down and the Roblox window is still active.

The only solution I see is to fire the hotkey upon release of the LButton using the [tilde prefix (~)](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Tilde) to prevent AHK from blocking the key-down/up events:

```
#IfWinActive, Roblox

    ~LButton Up:: SendInput, 1

#IfWinActive
```